# If $C_r^*(G)$ is purely infinite then every non-zero positive element of $C_0(G^{(0)})$ is infinite in $C_r^*(G)$

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Here $G$ is a groupoid and $G^{(0)}$ is its unit space. The statement seems trivially true but I don't see why exactly.

Edit: Definitions:

1. Infinite projection - A projection $p$ in a C*-algebra is infinite if it is Murray-vN equivalent to a proper subprojection. Equivalently, it is infinite if there exists a non-zero positive element a with $p\oplus a\precsim p$ where $\precsim$ means "Cuntz below"
2. Infinite positive element - Same as the last part of the above definition.
3. Purely infinite - A C*-algebra $A$ is purely infinite if, for each non-zero positive element $x$, the hereditary subalgebra $\overline{xAx}$ contains an infinite projection.

I don't know how to show every non-zero positive element in that subalgebra is a projection, let alone infinite. I don't how the two can be related. I know that every positive element is self-adjoint.

Comment: Hello, please try to ask questions in a more precise way. What is purely infinite? What is infinite? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Justdroppedin I have added the definitions and how I tried to go about the problem. I think the solution is a 1-liner as a research paper just says it is "trivial". So I do not have a line of argument that I am stuck with

Comment: And what is an infinite positive element? you only defined what an infinite projection is

Comment: I assume you're reading the paper of Brown, Orloff-Clark and Sierakowski. Look at the last line of the first paragraph in subsection 2.3, this justifies why they say it's "trivial". Also, you say "I don't know how to show every non-zero positive element in that subalgebra is a projection" -- this can never be true! as you said, infinite positive element is another definition, which is what you need to show

Comment: The definition given of purely infinite is only correct for simple C*-algebras. For non-simple C*-algebras, see the paper of Kirchberg-Rørdam called "Non-simple purely infinite C*-algebras" (AJM 2000)

Comment: @Justdroppedin and Jamie Gabe, you are right. I got the solution for my question. The triviality is just referring to another result in another paper which is not really easy to prove. But I thought there is a more direct proof in the simple case which I still don't know